# How to disable users changing their display_name?

Tags: users

What would I have to do to prevent users changing their display_name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery to disable the display name select.

```
function disable_display_name() {
    global $pagenow;
    if ( $pagenow == 'profile.php' ) {
    ?>
        <script>
            jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
                jQuery('#display_name').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
            });
        </script>
    <?php
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_head', 'disable_display_name', 15 );
```

Comment: NOTE: This solution only disables the form field. Should a User have any basic knowledge of HTML and/or modern web browsers, this can be quickly circumvented.

Comment: Sorry but it is not a good solution, I just disable Javascript to change it

Comment: @LaurenceCope There's no filter available to modify the HTML of the dropdown. It's either JavaScript or CSS. You'll have to restrict the users from accessing backend if you don't *trust* them.